# How to solve opacity and border radius conflict in IE 7 and 8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, opacity, css

I have added css to li element like below code:

```
#slider1 .overview li{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius:40px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc)
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: "alpha(opacity=50)";
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=50)";
    border: 3px solid #FFF; }
```

here i added PIE.htc file to support border radius and filter to support opacity for IE7 and IE8.

My problem is when i apply only filter to li element i am getting opacity properly. when i add PIE.htc file to support border radius for IE, opacity is not applying to li element.

Do you have any idea how to solve this conflict between filter and PIE.htc?

Comment: Can you add this on fiddle?

Comment: When it comes to these ancient dinosaur browsers, don't be too worried about looks. If the site functions properly and looks ok, then leave it there. Don't stress yourself out with all these little aesthetic details.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're going to get conflicts between CSS3Pie and `filter`. That's enevitable. `filter` has a number of known bugs where it conflicts with other browser features. CSS3Pie uses VML, and I'm really not surprised to hear of it conflicting with `filter`.

In fact, a quick search of the CSS3Pie issues shows that this is a known problem with CSS3Pie that has been logged for some time but not yet dealt with -- see https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/46

The first option I can suggest for you is to simply drop one of these features. I don't know how important rounded corners are to you in this particular element, but dropping it from IE by removing the reference to `pie.htc` would leave the `filter` to work on its own, so no conflict. The same would be true of removing the `filter` to just leave the rounded corners, although I suspect that dropping the opacity setting would make more of a difference to the usablility of the site than rounded corners.

The second option is to use an `rgba` colour for the background instead of `opacity`. Old IE versions don't support `rgba` colours, but CSS3Pie does, which means that you can do all the work for both the transparency effect and the rounded corners in CSS3Pie, which means you won't get a conflict. `rgba` is different to plain `opacity` - as it would make the background transparent but not affect the foreground (ie the text inside the element). This may be important, in which case it may not be a suitable solution, or it may be something you can live with.

The final option I can think of would be to ask the CSS3Pie authors if they would consider fixing the issue I linked earlier. That would probably require them to add `opacity` as a feature for CSS3Pie to polyfill. I imagine it would be a fairly large bit of work for them, but it may be something they'd consider doing if people ask for it. (that said, even if they did decide to do it, I doubt it would be done soon enough to be an answer you could use for your site).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to display two blue circles on a page, both with opacity. I found the best solution was to use a single blue pixel - saved out as a png with transparency...

```
    .transparent-blue {
        background: url(../../img/transparent-blue.png);
    }
```

...repeating as the background and not use the ms filter rule that was conflicting with pie.htc.

It is worthy to not that I only applied this solution to IE8, via a separate stylesheet...

```
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/ie8.css">
    <![endif]-->
```

in the main style sheet I used rgba as this is better for text (ie doesn't make the text opaque).

Comment: Could you expand a little on that. see [Is it okay to post a one-line answer, or would those be better as comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129019/is-it-okay-to-post-a-one-line-answer-or-would-those-be-better-as-comments)

Comment: Sorry @axrwkr  - I answered this a little to quickly. Hope this expansion helps.